# Remove specific result for requests_html

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

```
import datetime
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://music.apple.com/us/playlist/top-100-hong-kong/pl.7f35cffa10b54b91aab128ccc547f6ef'
applemusic = session.get(url)

applemusic.html.render(sleep=1, scrolldown=1)

data = applemusic.html.xpath('//*[@id="scrollable-page"]/main/div/div[2]', first=True)
artist_list = data.find('span.svelte-vyyb4r')

for artist in artist_list:
  print(artist)
```

Hi Guys, I am a newbie learner for python. I want to do a small function that can scape the information from the Apple Music playlist. But there is a row result that I want to remove it form the the output (you can see the following output result). How can I do it? I know this maybe a simple question but I really appreciate any kind assistance.

```
<Element 'span' class=('svelte-vyyb4r',)>
<Element 'span' class=('svelte-vyyb4r',)>
*<Element 'span' class=('songs-list-row__badge', 'songs-list-row__badge--explicit', 'svelte-vyyb4r')>*
<Element 'span' class=('svelte-vyyb4r',)>
<Element 'span' class=('svelte-vyyb4r',)>
```

I have try to remove() function but it seems not working

```
for artist in artist_list.remove("songs-list-row__badge"):
    print(artist)

Output
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: Try to avoid using deprecated packages: requests-html was last released on Feb 17, 2019, so it's pretty much unmaintained.

Comment: Looks like the web response is a XML format. Could you please share a dummy structure, 3 elements is enough to remove one.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus understand. As I want to scrape a website that is written in javascript, so I just google search a package that can render the website and find some people suggest requests-html. May I know if there is other packages that are recommended? Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Hermann12 I want to scrape the artist name form this website: https://music.apple.com/us/playlist/top-100-hong-kong/pl.7f35cffa10b54b91aab128ccc547f6ef  I think the xml format refer to following (sorry if it is not the correct format you mentioned)    <div class="songs-list-row__by-line svelte-vyyb4r" dir="auto"><span class="svelte-vyyb4r"><a data-testid="click-action" class="click-action" href="https://music.apple.com/us/artist/mc-cheung-tinfu/1532003825">MC Cheung Tinfu</a></span></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your CSS selector to only get the `span` elements that have only `svelte-vyyb4r` as class:

```py
data = applemusic.html.xpath('//*[@id="scrollable-page"]/main/div/div[2]', first=True)
artist_list = data.find('span[class="svelte-vyyb4r"]')
```

you can also loop through your list and check if it has the class you don't want and ignore it

```py
for artist in artist_list.remove():
    if "songs-list-row__badge" in artist.attrs["class"]:
        # skip element
        continue

    print(artist)
```

Comment: thanks! I use the your suggested css selector and it works. Much appreciate for your help.